# How to override configuration variables in settings.php

Tags: configuration

I need to override configuration variables declared in the settings.php. How this can be possible? Any help me on?

**Note**: I am trying to override a custom configuration variable, not any default one.

Comment: Refer https://coderwall.com/p/tdoztq

Comment: @ Krishna Mohan Thanks. But using variable_set(), it will override the configuration variable to the function in which it is used. If we try get the value of config variable in another function it will displays it again from settings.php. I need to override this in such a way that, wherever we try to fetch that variable the value will be the new one.

Comment: @akm That's not possible without rewriting `variable_get`

Comment: @Clive Thanks. So there is no possible way to override it without editing the settings.php?

Comment: Conf values in settings.php always "win"...they're supposed to be unconditional overrides, stuff that the programmer/site builder is saying to Drupal "don't change these, I need them to be exactly this for my site to work". So to override a var set in settings.php, you need to change it in settings.php (or change the way `variable_get` works)

Comment: Clive is correct that if you set `$conf['myvariable']` in settings.php, it will win out, and cannot be changed. Usually, though, you want to change 'myvariable' because it controls something. Possibly a better question to ask is what you want to be able to change. Depending upon what that is, you may find there is an alternate strategy to change Drupal's behavior. But we'd need to know which variable you were changing.

Comment: I am trying to override a custom configuration variable, not any default one.

Answer (score -1):

You can't overwrite the variables in settings.php.